# UIImageView over Navigation bar and main screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an UImage that I need half on the navigation bar and half on the main screen. I have added a Navigation Controller on my project so now I have a nav bar on all screens. I need a square image to go half on the navigation controller and half on the main screen.

In XCODE I have successfully put an UImageView over the nav bar and the main screen but when i put an image on it i only appears in the part thats over the main screen and not over the navigation bar. I don't want to split the image so I can use Navigationbar.image control - is there another way ?

Comment: How do you add the `UIImageView`? Can you show your code?

Comment: I have not used code, I have used the XCODE gui to put the UIImageView over the navigation controller and main screen.

Comment: Built in Nav bar is by default on the top...you can't change this. If you have seen somewhere, then that was customised by hiding original

Comment: can you post some code or screen shot of storyboard you are trying ?

Comment: @user3307144 I see. Well I'm not sure this can be done via the storyboard (what you refer to as Xcode gui) but it can be done in code. If this is an option for you let me know and I'll write an answer.

Comment: In code would be fab Gad..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding it to viewController, add it to window.

```
UIView *view =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 30,240,60)];
view.backgroundColor =[UIColor greenColor];
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window addSubview:view];
```

Comment: that didn't work in the ViewDidLoad, i guess that would give me a green block

Comment: the old code with keywindow won't work because, it was nil initially. now with edited code, iam sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

As you might have noticed the `UINavigationBar` appears on top of everything you have within your `UIViewController`'s view.
One way of overcoming this is by adding your `UIImageView` to the `keyWindow` like so:

```
UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:imageView];
```